# Azure DevOps pipeline error: Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated

Tags: azure-devops

I try to create SQL Server with ARM on Azure DevOps.
Pipeline successfully create SQL Server resource to Azure Portal, but I'm getting strange errors in Azure DevOps. Why this occurs and how to fix?

ERROR:

```
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
##[error]RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted: Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not 
allowed to be updated.
##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment? 
view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

YML:

```
task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'TestRG-Conn'
    subscriptionId: '1111753a-501e-4e46-9aff-6120ed561111'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'TestRG'
    location: 'North Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CreateSQLServer/azuredeploy.json'
   csmParametersFile: 
'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CreateSQLServer/azuredeploy.parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

VARIABLE IN TEMPLATE:

```
"variables": {
"StorageBlobContributor": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '111111111111111111111-')]"
```

},

RESOURCE IN TEMPLATE:

```
"resources": [
        {
         "condition": "[parameters('enableADS')]",
         "type": 
"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
          "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
          "name": "[concat(variables('storageName'), 
'/Microsoft.Authorization/', variables('uniqueRoleGuid') )]",
           "dependsOn": [
             "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', 
 parameters('serverName'))]",
             "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 
 variables('storageName'))]"
          ],
           "properties": {
            "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('StorageBlobContributor')]",
             "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', 
 parameters('serverName')), '2018-06-01-preview', 
  'Full').identity.principalId]",
             "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 
 variables('storageName'))]",
             "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
           }
         }
```

Comment: can you share your template and parameters file? you are clearly attempting to update read-only properties on the sql server

Comment: I wonder if problem is in ""StorageBlobContributor": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '111111111111111111111-')]".. What is this ID that I should use? Does Service Principal need permission to AD?

Comment: no, what its saying - is this role assignmend already exists and you are trying to update it, change its name, i think that should help

Comment: Hi Kenny_I,any update on this ticket. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that 4c74356b41 suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 40):

Chances are you have deployed and deleted the resources, however, the role assignment is still there and that is what it is clashing with (what 4c7... is saying). So, go check the permissions on the storage account - if you use managed identities, that identity will be deleted but the role assignment will persists and show the user as 'unknown' which will also cause the above error when trying to deploy again - had the same issue but with a managed identity I was using for an aks cluster. Frustrating.

When you deleted a managed identity it does not delete associated roles created for it, I wish it cleaned up properly.

Comment: Great answer! It is amazing that these don't get deleted automatically - it's like they want you to fall into the pit of despair

Comment: Indeed. You should go to Resouce Group role assignments or even, Subscription role assignments. Probably you will see "Identity not found" with active role assignments. This same issue happens when you try to redeploy a recently deleted MSI from Bicep.

Comment: Is there any way to check if the role exists and so don't try to recreate it?

Comment: Just had the same problem - one solution is to delete the entire resource group before re-deploying - the role assignment will be deleted too.

Comment: You don't need to delete the entire resource group, just look for the orphan role assignments and delete those. I must say, it's a real trap and I'm surprised MS allows this behaviour!

Comment: https://jloudon.com/cloud/Removing-Unknown-Azure-RBAC-Role-Assignments-with-PowerShell/ this link has PowerShell scripts to do cleanup.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, it was the name of the RoleAssignment. It was unique on the Resource Group level but not on the subscription level. Not sure what is the scope for the uniqueness of the name.

Comment: How is this different from @Richard answer?

Comment: Maybe I should have posted this as a comment but in my caes there was no role assignment on the reasorce in question.

Comment: I just checked, the uniqueness scope is the AAD tenant. That is, you can't have the same GUID in two subscriptions in the same tenant, but you can have the same GUID in two different tenants.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson - "How is this different from Richard answer?" - To me, berzns answer is much more understandable, and helped me figuring this problem out :)

Comment: this just hit me, and your answer saved my tail !  thank you.    my guid was not unique to the entire tenant.  i had to add the resourceGroup().id to the hash, so that it made it stable (always the same) and still unique inside the entire tenant.

Comment: this was my issue, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Bouncing off @Richard answer, I didn't have the permission to delete the "ghost" managed identities so I deployed the same role assignment under a different guid by adding an additional string to the `guid()` function. [String functions for ARM templates docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#guid)

To do this, I changed my `roleNameGuid`'s value from

`"[guid(resourceGroup().id)]"` to

`"[guid(resourceGroup().id, parameters('guid_seed'))]"`, where `parameters('guid_seed')` is an arbitrary string that is passed from DevOps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use this when I need to assign an RBAC role, the more details provided in the name the better I have found out it behaves. It really needs to be unique:

```
resource rbacRole 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(resourceGroup().id, serviceBusTopic.id, roledef.id, funcApp.id)
...
}
```