# Azure Bicep - Role Assignment in a different subcription

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

Trying to assign a managed identity to a Resource Group in a separate subscription in the same tenant. I can achieve this via the Azure portal. My Main.bicep, something like this:

```
targetScope = 'subscription'

module rgRoleAssignment 'modules/MyModule.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup('anotherSubscriptionId', 'myResourceGroupName')
  name: 'qwerty123'
  params: {
    principalId: MyManagedIdentity.outputs.principalId
    roleDefinitionIds: ['7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d'] //ACRPull
  }
}
```

MyModule.bicep:

```
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'

param roleDefinitionIds array
param roleAssignmentDescription string = ''
param principalId string 

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = [for roleDefinitionId in roleDefinitionIds: {
    name: guid(roleDefinitionId, resourceGroup().id)
    scope: resourceGroup()
    properties: {
        description: roleAssignmentDescription
        principalId: principalId
        roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleDefinitionId)
        principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    }
}]
```

This returns the dreaded "Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated. (Code: RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted)" error, which usually means there are orphaned role assignments around the place, but I can't see any. What am I missing?

Comment: This error comes when you are deploying role assignments with the same `guid()` multiple times. Doing that gives `guid` name results to this error. Refer [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/85388#issuecomment-997458280) once. @Ben Power

Comment: Check this [explanation](https://jasonmasten.com/2021/04/13/tenant-id-application-id-principal-id-and-scope-are-not-allowed-to-be-updated/#main) too. @Ben Power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated. (Code: RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted)" error: -

The cause of this error could be a name conflict in most of the cases. Change the name of your role assignment which is nothing but a `GUID` to a value that has not been used to deploy a role assignment before.

Refer [blog](https://jasonmasten.com/2021/04/13/tenant-id-application-id-principal-id-and-scope-are-not-allowed-to-be-updated/#main) by @Jason Masten & [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/85310) issue for the relevant information.

> Verify the scope of the uniqueness of your resource names. Use appropriate seed values for the [uniqueString() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-string#uniquestring) to ensure that you can reuse the Bicep file across Azure resource groups and subscriptions as given in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/patterns-name-generation#considerations).

After checking the above, I tried to deploy it in my environment with the above-mentioned changes and was able to deploy successfully as shown.

`Module.bicep`:

```bash
targetScope = 'subscription'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
module rgRoleAssignment 'iden.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup('subscription_ID','resourceGroup')
  name: 'qwerty123'
  params: {
    principalId: useridentiy.properties.principalId
    roleDefinitionIds: ['7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d']
  }
}
```

`Identity.bicep`:

```bash
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'
param roleDefinitionIds array
param roleAssignmentDescription string = ''
param principalId string 

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = [for roleDefinitionId in roleDefinitionIds: {
    name: guid(resourceGroup().id, principalId, roleDefinitionId)
    scope: resourceGroup()
    properties: {
        description: roleAssignmentDescription
        principalId: principalId
        roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleDefinitionId)
        principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    }
}]
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

You can also refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63461054/19785512) by @Richard for the similar issue.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!